# Generating script of database from source control TFS folder

Tags: tfs, ssms

I have database objects in source control like there is separate file of each procedure table and function

I want to create one Database script like which is generate from SSMS though generate script

How can i generate such script from TFS

Comment: TFS doesn't sound like the right tool for the job.  TFS Source control just manages source code, it doesn't do script generation.  It sounds like you probably want some sort of Database project, but as it stands, I doubt you'll get a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SQL Compare](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-compare/) will do this for you, although it depends whether it can read your file format. However, I don't see why this should be a problem asssuming the files are SQL creation scripts.

Once you've downloaded and installed SQL Compare, load your folder of scripts on the left hand side datasource (using the source control/scripts folder selection), and put a put a blank database on the right hand side datasource (just create one in SSMS). Do a comparison, run through the deployment wizard, and you'll be able to save off a single script that includes all of your objects in correct dependency order.

The tool has a 14=day fully functional trial so you'll be able to easily discover whether this works for you.